# Хранение ссылок на UI элементы в юнити(разобрался)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возник вопрос хранения ссылок на Ui элементы по типу private Text _scoreText или МНОЖЕСТВО панелей что бы в каждом классе где затрагиваю UI не кидать туда ссылки и не думать где их найти Т.К многие элементы тупо выключены по началу.В голову пришла идея сделать полностью статический класс где прописаны все ссылки на UI и просто в нужном месте скрипта использовать уже закешированные ссылки на UI элементы,правильно ли это будет,или есть какие то более практичные реализации.

Comment: Так в чем проблема `[SerializeField] private` полей? SerializeField для того и нужно, чтобы видеть приватную переменную в инспекторе (я не затрагиваю сериализацию)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Ну вот у меня есть слот он префаб вот я поставил серилайзфилд,но из за того что он префаб объект со сцены в него не перетащу,а делать все панели префабами как по мне глупо.

Comment: Вы крайне мутно описали проблему. Что за "классы затрагивающие ui". Вы чего-то не понимаете и городище какую-то фигню от которой сами и страдаете. Фигачить статику это не идея, а крик безысходности. Статика это плохо.